# What happened to Vanko's legs in Iron Man 2?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, marvel, iron-man-2

In the fight at Monaco, after Iron Man beats Vanko, and removes the Arc reactor from Vanko's suit, the cops drag him away, and he appears to have lost his legs.  They look amputated.

But later this never comes back up, he walks around no problem.

Was this a plot line they were going to follow, filmed, and then ditched?

Comment: Related [How was Vanko not crippled by being crushed repeatedly between a Bentley and a wall?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80365/how-was-vanko-not-crippled-by-being-crushed-repeatedly-between-a-bentley-and-a-w)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Vanko does not lose his legs in the fight. It is just an artefact of the camera angle.

.

If you notice the scene closely one leg is bent at the knee which he straightens a split second before the scene ends. The shoe of the other falls off and what you see is his feet and not the stump of his leg.

[image: A screen shot showing both his legs intact after the fight]

Comment: @Bharart B I see watching it over and over on YouTube it is a little more clear they are not stumps, but it does look that was for a bit.

Comment: Your first video link has gone dead.