# Does Ivan Vanko's first suit enhance his strength, or is he supposed to be incredibly strong?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-2

Ivan Vanko's first suit (the one he used to attack Tony when he was racing) doesn't cover his whole body, and at first sight you can't really tell if it's enhancing his strength, however, he's able to throw around Tony along with his Iron Man suit, which according to some sources should weight around 425 lbs.

Does Ivan Vanko's first suit enhance his strength, or is he supposed to be incredibly strong?

Comment: (I probably should write this as an answer, but since it's lacking, I guess I'll leave it there) His suit looked like an exoskeleton. Real life purely mechanical exoskeletons can sometimes be used to assist people in walking even when they can't stand on their own because they're too weakened for example. Also, see "industrial exoskeleton".

Comment: https://www.therobotreport.com/industrial-exoskeletons/ "Industrial exoskeletons is the collective name given to mechanical devices worn by workers, whose construction mirrors the structure of operator’s limbs, joints, and muscles, works in tandem with them, and is utilized as a _capabilities amplifier_, or as a fatigue and strain reducer."

Comment: As a side note, the task of creating those exoskeletons so that they work without snapping limbs in half is surprisingly tricky.

Comment: I would point out that it was Tony's briefcase suit in that.  And I doubt Tony can lift even 250 lbs with one hand, so that weight estimate is pretty high.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to this (according to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/80378/23243)) Marvel-sanctioned graphic, yes, it provides enhanced strength.

[image: Infographic of Whiplash suit] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

> Hydraulic arm and leg attachments increase Whiplash's strength by roughly three times.

Comment: 425lbs/3 should be liftable by a human

Comment: @AncientSwordRage He'd still have to be pretty strong, especially to actually get anything moving at that weight - 425/3 = 141 lbs (63kg) is still very heavy, and an average human would struggle mightily to lift that weight, let alone throw it around. But then, we're talking about superhero logic, so ordinary humans need not apply.

Comment: This might be a good reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_throw along with https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143609/6698

Comment: Also worth pointing out in case some people come with half-knowledge: 61kg is perfectly doable for many types of weightlifting disciplines, even easy for some. But there’s a pretty big difference between a controlled lift of a static object off the ground, and just tossing around something something that heavy while the thing thing you’re tossing doesn’t want to be tossed.

Comment: [Plugging two data points from that wiki link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=25+%3D+a%2F%2825%2Bb%29%3B+30+%3D+a%2F%2812%2Bb%29), to find the coefficients of the formula from the physics.se you can make [a guess that he could throw Tony 16 meters.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y+%3D+a%2F%28x%2Bb%29%3B+x%3D63%2C+a+%3D+1950%2C+b+%3D+53)

Comment: I am nowhere near as muscular as Ivan Vanko; I cannot deadlift and throw 141 lbs without considerably difficulty (even then it would need to be an easily-liftable form like a barbell) but I can easily grab a 141-lb person who is standing in front of me and, through a combination of pulling and twisting my body & arms, more or less _toss_ them in a direction I want. It's _much_ easier if they are already moving toward me, because I can make use of their momentum. "Roughly" three times could also mean something else like 3.3, though. Now we're talking 128.8 lbs (58.4 kg)... noticeably lighter!